# How to pass a div_id to jquery load function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, load

I have a story model that has many posts.  I list the stories in an index view without each story's posts.  When a user clicks on one of the stories in the index view I want to load that story's posts via calling stories/(story_id)/posts using the ajax .load function, and make sure to put the posts into that  story's correct div (created by "<%= div_for(story, "posts_bucket_for") do %>")

The problem is, I don't know how to pass the correct story_id to the .load function or how to make sure that the resulting posts are loaded into the correct posts_bucket_for.

Here's my _story.html.erb file:

```
<%= div_for(story) do %>
   <%= div_for(story, "heading_for") do %>
        <span class=story_title>
            <%= story.title.titleize %>
        </span>
        <span class=story_post_amount>
            # of posts: <%= story.posts.length %>
        </span>
   <% end %>
<%= div_for(story, "posts_bucket_for") do %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my PostController#index action

```
  def index
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @posts = @story.posts
    respond_with(@posts, :api_template => :public, :root => :posts)
  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You have to make the storyID available from whatever is being clicked on (likely as an attribute in the HTML).  You can then use that storyID to construct the URL (using string math) you want for the .load() and then pass that as the URL parameter when calling .load().  FYI, when you post an erb file instead of actual generated HTML, you limit those who can help you to those who know Rails rather than those who know HTML.

Comment: point taken about posting the erb file.  My biggest question (being a newbie) was how to extract a rails created html element id for use in the load (or get) function.  I attached the erb file because the element ids are created by rails in that file.  Max' answer shows me how to do it, and makes me feel rather dumb because I should have seen it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to implement a solution (this is for Rails 3).

According to the Rails documentation for [`div_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for), `div_for(story, :class => "story")` will produce HTML that looks like:

```
<div id="story_123" class="story"> Your content </div>
```

So, with jQuery, you could run something like:

```
// Attach click event handlers to your story divs
$(function() {
  $("div.story").click(function() {
    // Get the HTML ID of the story div
    html_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // Extract the database id
    story_id = html_id.split("_")[1];
    // Call your handy function to load story posts
    loadStoryPosts(story_id);
  });
});
```

For your buckets, I would not use another `div_for(story)`. This would result in you having two `divs` on the page with the same ID. Instead, I would do something like this:

```
<%= div_for(story, :class => "story") do %>
    <p>The story</p>
    <div class="posts" />
<% end %>
```

And then, in jQuery

```
// Make an AJAX request to your Rails server
function loadStoryPosts(story_id) {
  // This is a jQuery AJAX GET request to your stories/:id/posts route
  $.get("stories/" + story_id + "/posts", function(data) {
    html_id = "story_" + story_id;        
    // Insert the result of the request into the appropriate posts bucket
    $("#"+html_id+" .posts").html(data);
  });
}
```

The remaining task is to have a controller action handle the AJAX request and return the posts to be inserted onto the page.

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  def posts
    story = Story.find params[:id]
    # Render the story's posts inside a partial (without any layout)
    render :partial => "stories/posts", :locals => { :posts => story.posts }, :layout => false
  end
end
```

You'll also want to create a partial to render the posts. In my example, this would be `views/stories/_posts.html.erb`.

This is a lot of new learning material if you haven't dealt with AJAX+Rails before, so here are a couple useful tutorials: [here](http://www.petermac.com/rails-3-jquery-and-multi-select-dependencies/) and [here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/).

Comment: Thanks Max.  I have a comment and a question.  First, the comment.  Notice that I created my post buckets using the rails helper: <%= div_for(story, "posts_bucket_for") do %>.  The optional "post_bucket_for" will create divs with ids like: posts_bucket_for_story_1.  So, I don't have a problem of multiple elements with the same dom ids.  Now for the question.  The get() function seems to load my posts/index.js.erb file without executing the js.  How can I make sure that the js file executes?  Or, alternatively, how can I just render the posts/index.html.erb file? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding div_for. Can you clarify what you mean by "the index.js.erb gets loaded but not executed"?

Comment: Just figured it out. turns out that I didn't really want to load the file.  I just wanted to make a get request to my posts#index action using js.  That way my post/index.js.erb file would execute. I still needed the story_id of the story that was clicked so to pass it to the index action, and your answer showed me how to extract it.  As for what I was experiencing . . . I was loading the text of the posts/index.js.html file into the dom when what I really wanted to do was execute it.  Thanks for your help. I'm on my way!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing what you are trying to achieve and, I bet, many of the contributors here will give you a solution based on their coding experience. Here is mine:

First and foremost, you must decide if you need to keep the story title visible or not once you "upload" the actual story to the point you want.

I have no idea about ruby or ruby-on-rails but have a very good track on "blogging".

Let's say that from your database you listed the stories available as

```
<div id='story1' onClick='showStory(1); ' >Story 1</div>
<div id='story2' onClick='showStory(2); ' >Story 2</div>
<div id='story3' onClick='showStory(3); ' >Story 3</div>
<div id='story4' onClick='showStory(n); ' >Story n</div>

function showStory(storyNumber) {
    $.get('url-of-the-story-storyNumber', function (data) {
        $('#story'+storyNumber).html(data);
    });
}
or
function showStory(storyNumber) {
     $('#story'+storyNumber).load('url-of-the-story-storyNumber');
}
```

If you plan on not overwriting the story title line, you just drop another div into the story line:

```
<div onClick='showStory(1); ' >
 Story 1
 <div id='story1' ></div>
</div>

<div onClick='showStory(2); ' >
 Story 2
 <div id='story2' ></div>
</div>

<div onClick='showStory(3); ' >
 Story 3
 <div id='story3' ></div>
</div>

<div onClick='showStory(n); ' >
 Story n
 <div id='storyn' ></div>
</div>
```

The easier you make your IDs "manageable" the easier will be to make manuevers with them.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, zequinha.  This gets me a large part of the way to the answer.  I'm going to check maxs' answer though, because he shows me how to extract the element ids that are dynamically created by rails helper methods.